# Firefox & Safari "unexpected '*' token", Not in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I've made this function:

```
changeTimeFormat :function(timeCode){
  var timeCodes = timeCode.split(/[:.]+/),
      hh = timeCodes[0],
      mm = timeCodes[1],
      ss = timeCodes[2],
      msmsms = timeCodes[3],
      newTimeCode = (hh * 60**2) + (mm * 60) + (ss*1) + (msmsms / 1000);
  return newTimeCode;
}
```

...Which gets a certain timecode and changes its format from HH:MM:SS,MsMsMs to SS.MsMs.

It works like a charm on Chrome, but Safari and FireFox throw a "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '*'" message, regarding the first '*' sign, when loading the script. Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: you better use Math functions, I think safari and firefox haven't supported that kind of algebraic operations yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believed the error is because of `60**2` which I believed not supported in firefox or safari yet (please correct me if i'm wrong)

The other way arround this is to use `Math.pow(base,exponent)`

```
changeTimeFormat :function(timeCode){
   var timeCodes = timeCode.split(/[:.]+/),
   hh = timeCodes[0],
   mm = timeCodes[1],
   ss = timeCodes[2],
   msmsms = timeCodes[3],
   newTimeCode = (hh * Math.pow(60,2)) + (mm * 60) + (ss*1) + (msmsms / 1000);
  return newTimeCode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it.